# Writing to postgres table over SSH with python

Tags: python, postgresql, ssh

I have a VM that I can log into by SSH. I have a postgres server hosted there.

I have a program on the "server side" that I call with

`spark-submit --jars postgresql-42.6.0.jar h5test.py testH5.h5`

It does some processing and writes to a table by

`sparkDF.write.jdbc(jdbc_url, arr[i].replace("/","_"), properties=connection_properties)`

I wrote a program in python on the "client side" that can connect to the postgres server and pull data out by

```
    def printTable(self, name):
        print("Printing table: " + name[0])
        with SSHTunnelForwarder(        
            (ip_address, port), #Remote server IP and SSH port
            ssh_username = "name",
            ssh_password = "pass",
            remote_bind_address=('localhost', port)) as server: #PostgreSQL server IP and sever port on remote machine
            
            server.start() #start ssh sever
            print ('Server connected via SSH')
            
            #connect to PostgreSQL
            #local_port = str(server.local_bind_port)
            local_port=str(server.local_bind_port)
            engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:' + local_port +'/tableName')
    
            Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
            session = Session()
            
            print ('Database session created')
            sqlCommand = "select * from " + name[0] + ";"
            dataTest = session.execute(sqlCommand)
            for row in dataTest:
                print(row)
            session.close()
```

The process now is to connect on ssh, send a file over to the "server", then call the "server side" program with the file name. Is is possible that instead of having to call a program that writes to the local postgres server, that I can connect to the postgres on my side *and* write the data to it from the "client side"?